# Login ASP (AD) How to modify UserName value before authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm having some troubles on ASP authentication:

Users can connect via an ordinary Login view.
I want those who know to be able to connect as someone else. To do so, if they type
username**_as**, an other textbox appears and they can type the user they want to connect as.

My problem is that I let default behavior of ASP(and web.config) handles everything so far.
So when the user click on login, the username is username_as (and is obviously not recognized ;))

What I want is to send username (without the suffix) but I don't know where I can split the textbox value.

(I've started to do dirty stuff but I guess there is a proper way of doing it right? :))

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mention web.config - is this a classic asp question or is it asp.net?

Comment: It's asp.net (wrote the wrong tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done to solve my problem was adding a OnClientClick event on the Sign In button. 
In this function I just modify the value of LoginUser_UserName.
It works for the click but also on the Enter validation.

Not super clean but it works. (And I didn't have to implement in the code behind the AD authentication)